# Getting error in R trying to calculate mean on column that contains NA

Tags: r, mean, na.rm

From searching online and in this group, it seems like this should work:

```
> mean(r_lab$ozone, na.rm=TRUE)
```

However, what I get is:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(r_lab$ozone, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

**This is the contents of that column in the dataset:**

```
> r_lab$Ozone
 [1]  41  36  12  18  NA  28  23  19   8  NA   7  16  11  14
[15]  18  14  34   6  30  11   1  11   4  32  NA  NA  NA  23
```

I'm sort of flustered.

Comment: What is the result of `class(r_lab$ozone)`?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with. When I assign your values to a vector & run your code, I get a mean & no error.

Comment: It could be a factor column.  Convert to numeric and it would work. i.e. `mean(as.numeric(as.character(r_lab$ozone)), na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  Yes, that is true, but the warning message usually occurs with factors i.e. `mean(factor(1:5))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(factor(1:5)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: "argument is not numeric or logical". That doesn't leave many choices. A factor class is quite likely, IMO. It would be necessary to post the output requested by @RichardScriven

Comment: Class returns integer.  I only showed the first 30 rows.  There's 153 rows altogether, and more columns.

Comment: @David If you are using `typeof`, it returns `integer` as `factor` is stored internally as `integer`

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. There is information in the link above.

Comment: Wait, you wrote `ozone` in the first one and `Ozone` in the last one.  Do you have two columns of the same name with different caps?

Comment: First few rows of all columns

> r_lab
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day

1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1

2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2

3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3

Comment: Crap.  It's case sensitive.  Ozone worked.  ozone did not.  My apologies, and many thanks.

Comment: Lol.  Yeah so you were effectively doing `mean(NULL, na.rm = TRUE)`.  Gotta watch out for those caps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware that R was case sensitive.

Richard was right, I should have been using Ozone, not ozone.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Sorry, I did not know how to provide reproducible data.  What would have been sufficient in this case?

Comment: Copy and paste the result from the `dput()` function.  That is the reproducible code.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, where I made your example reproducible.

Comment: You can learn how to provide a reproducible example in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) I provided initially. That's why I provided it.

Answer (score 6):

Your data is most likely of class `character`, instead of numeric.

Take a look at these examples:

```
# Set up some numeric data
x <- c(41, 36, 12, 18, NA, 28, 23, 19,  8, NA,  7, 16, 11, 14, 18, 14, 34,  6, 30, 11,  1, 11,  4, 32, NA, NA, NA, 23)

# Clearly taking the mean on this will work
 mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)

[1] 18.13043
```

However, if your data is of class `character`, then you get the error message you report:

```
y <- as.character(x)
mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(y, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

So you should convert your data to numeric first, then take the mean:

```
mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE)

[1] 18.13043
```

Comment: The only problem is that `as.character(x)` displays with double quotes around each entry. This is not what the OP has posted.

Comment: @RHertel Who knows what the OP posted - no reproducible example, so it's all guess work, isn't it. After his last update, it seems (s)he simply made a spelling mistake. Still, this answer is most likely what really happened.